Variety with points locally everywhere but no adelic points
Let $X$ be a smooth geometrically integral variety over a number field $K$. In general, the set of adelic points $X(\mathbf{A}_K)$ and the product of local points $\prod_{v \in \Omega_k} X(K_v)$ are really different.

Does there exists a variety $X$ such that $X(\mathbf{A}_K) = \emptyset$ and $\prod_{v \in \Omega_k} X(K_v) \neq \emptyset $?

My intuition tells me that such a variety should exist, but I couldn't come up with an example and I found no example in the literature.
I was also wondering if such examples are pathological.

Is there a "nice" class of (non proper) varieties over $K$ such that for every $X$ in such class $X(\mathbf{A}_K) = \emptyset$ if and only if $\prod_{v \in \Omega_k} X(K_v) = \emptyset $? Is this true for homogeneous spaces of algebraic groups?


So your question is: let $\mathcal{O}$ be the ring of $S$-integers of a number field $K$ (where $S$ is a finite set of places of $K$). Is there a nice $\mathcal{O}$-scheme $\mathcal{X}$ such that for every place $v$ of $K$, $\mathcal{X}(K_v)$ has a point, but for infinitely many places $v \notin S$ of $K$, $\mathcal{X}(\mathcal{O}_{K_v})$ is empty?

Yes, that's exactly what I'm looking for :)

Assume that $X$ is quasi-compact. I will sketch a proof (using mostly overkill arguments and a copious amount of “spread out” ideas that I will not detail) that the answer to the question is negative.
In fact, what we do is show that there is a suitable integral model $\mathcal{X}$ of $X$ such that, for all but finitely many places $v$ of $K$ (in a way that can in principle be made explicit for a given “suitable model”), $\mathcal{X}$ contains an $\mathcal{O}_{K_v}$-point.
By standard arguments (I hope), we may assume that $X$ is the generic fibre of a smooth $\mathcal{O}$-scheme $\mathcal{X}$, where $\mathcal{O}$ is the ring of $S$-integers of $K$ for some finite set $S$ of places of $K$ containing all the infinite places.
The key claim is the following:
We can choose $S$ and $\mathcal{X}$ such that the following holds. Let $v \notin S$ be a finite place of $K$ with residue field $k_v$. Then $\mathcal{X}(k_v) \neq 0$.
If this claims holds, then, since $\mathcal{X}$ is smooth, any point in $\mathcal{X}(k_v)$ lifts to a point in $\mathcal{X}(\mathcal{O}_{K_v})$, and we are done.
To prove the claim, we will need more work.
First, by Nagata, Hironaka and standard “spreading out” arguments (after if needed changing $\mathcal{X}$ and $S$), we may assume that $\mathcal{X}$ is a dense open subscheme of a proper smooth $\mathcal{O}$-scheme $\overline{\mathcal{X}}$, and such that $\mathcal{X}$ is dense in every fibre of $\overline{\mathcal{X}} \rightarrow \mathrm{Spec}\,\mathcal{O}$.
Let $\mathcal{Z}=\overline{\mathcal{X}} \backslash \mathcal{X}$.
Let $v \notin S$: the goal is then to show that when $|k_v|$ is large enough, $|\overline{\mathcal{X}}(k_v)| > |\mathcal{Z}(k_v)|$.
The first term can be estimated using the Weil conjectures and the Grothendieck trace formula: one has $|\overline{\mathcal{X}}(k_v)|\sim |k_v|^{\dim{X}}$.
Hence, our goal is to show that $|\mathcal{Z}(k_v)|=o(|k_v|^{\dim{X}})$.
Write $\mathcal{Z}=\cup_{i}{U_i}$, where $U_i$ is an affine open subscheme. By Noether normalization (and spreading out), after removing finitely many $v$ from $S$, we may assume that there are finite morphisms $U_i \rightarrow \mathbb{A}^{d_i}_{\mathcal{O}}$ of $\mathcal{O}$-schemes with maximal degree $r_i$, where $d_i$ is the dimension of the generic fibre of $U_i$ (so that $d_i < \dim{X}$).
This implies that for $v \notin S$, $|\mathcal{Z}(k_v)| \leq \sum_i{r_i|k_v|^{d_i}} = o(|k_v|^{\dim{X}})$, whence the conclusion.

Thank you very much for the answer. Isn't your key claim a direct consequence of Lang-Weil estimates?

Basically yes, but there’s an important twist: we need Lang-Weil estimates that are uniform with respect to the base field.

I think Lang-Weil estimates are uniform with respect to the base field. For example in Theorem 7.7.1 of Rational points on varieties.

By the way, I just realised that Theorem 7.7.2 in Rational points on varieties (at least its proof) is exactly what I was looking for

Yes, that’s exactly it. I wasn’t aware of this specific write-up, but this argument looked so standard that there had to be a reference.
